# spring framework: How can i start a web project with eclipse j2ee indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm on debian-6.

I have install ant,tomcat6,openjdk-6-jre.

Now from eclipse which project would i create as spring framework ?

I'm also following this => http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html
But i can't understand how to start with eclipse for spring framework MVC .

Did i miss anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Spring Source Tool Suite (STS)](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) -- it is an free Eclise provided by Spring Source containing the plugins you need (spring ide, m2eclipse, aspectJ, ...). So you do not need to download them all by hand.

It is fully compatible with the normal Eclipse so you can install all other plugins you want to have.

*Btw as far as I know, the Spring IDE contains not all the features that STS provides.*

STS contains in the new project wizard the category: "SpringSource Tool Suite" (not "Spring"). Within this category is the Project template "Spring Template Projet". After selecting this you can choose what you need. For example "Spring MVC Project".

Answer (score 3):

Open your Eclipse go to **Help>Eclipse Marketplace** and search Spring IDE. Install it and at the end (afer installation and eclipse restart) you should have a spring project menu on **File>New** tab. But i suggest you to use maven instead of ant to build you apps.